# Python File Remains Empty After Writing to it Issue

Tags: python

I am trying to read URL directly from `MYSQLDB` table and `tldextract` to get the domain from the url and find the SPF(Sender Policy Framework) Record for the domain.

When i'm trying to write the SPF records of each and every domain i scan,My `Ouput_SPF_Records.txt` do not contain any records i write.

Not sure with the issue,Any suggestions please ?

```
import sys
import socket
import dns.resolver
import re
import MySQLdb
import tldextract
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode

def getspf (domain):
   answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
   for rdata in answers:
        for txt_string in rdata.strings:
                if txt_string.startswith('v=spf1'):
                        return txt_string.replace('v=spf1','')

db=MySQLdb.connect("x.x.x.x","username","password","db_table")
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT application_id,url FROM app_info.app_urls")
data=cursor.fetchall()
x=0
while x<len(data):
        c=tldextract.extract(data[x][1])
        #print c
        app_id=data[x][0]
        #print app_id
        d=str(app_id)+','+c[1]+'.'+c[2]
        #with open('spfout.csv','a') as out:
        domain=smart_str(d)
        #print domain
        with open('Ouput_SPF_Records.txt','w') as g:
                full_spf=""
                spf_rec=""
                y=domain.split(',')
                #print "y===",y,y[0],y[1]
                app_id=y[0]
                domains=y[1]
                try:   
                        full_spf=getspf(domains.strip())+"\n"
                        spf_rec=app_id+","+full_spf
                        print spf_rec
                except Exception:
                     pass
                g.write(spf_rec)
        x=x+1
        g.close()
```

Comment: Not sure if it resolves it, but you don't need to close `g`. Due to the `with open() as g:` thingy, it is automatically closed.

Comment: Why do you ignore the exception `except Exception: pass`?

Comment: `g.write(spf_rec)` is called after you might have ignored an exception. That could make `spf_rec` not be set.

Comment: @PeterWood When i do get any error while getting the SPF record for a particular domain,I made an exception there and pass it on it next domain to scan ! Correct me if im wrong Please !

Comment: @Arun You should use `except ExceptionName:` so you don't accidentally  ignore unexpected errors (which I suspect you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try openning the file with append mode, instead of `w` mode. `w` mode overwrites the file in each iteration. Example -

```
with open('Ouput_SPF_Records.txt','a') as g:
```

Most probably, the last time you open the file in write mode, you do not write anything in since, you are catching and ignoring all exceptions , which causes the empty file.

Also, if you know the error which you are expecting, you should use `except <Error>:` instead of `except Exception:` . Example -

```
try:   
    full_spf=getspf(domains.strip())+"\n"
    spf_rec=app_id+","+full_spf
    print spf_rec
except <Error you want to catch>:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you open the file many times, each time through the loop. You use `w` mode, which erases the contents and writes from the beginning.

Either open the file once before the loop, or open in append mode `a`, so you don't delete the previously written data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Debug your code and try to figure out the problem.
also note that :
1. You shouldn't just write 'pass' in the try/except block. Deal with the Exception

2.

```
 with open('Ouput_SPF_Records.txt','w') as g:
```

it will automatically close the file, so there is no need to do : **g.close()** explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the result of getspf return None by default.
The Problem is that python cant concatenate str and NoneType (the type of None) (which throws an exception that you quickly discard).

You may try this instead:

```
def getspf (domain):
   answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
   for rdata in answers:
        for txt_string in rdata.strings:
                if txt_string.startswith('v=spf1'):
                        return txt_string.replace('v=spf1','')
   return ""#"Error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should check for the exception, my guess is that statements inside it are not performed, and spf_rec is left to "".
As per POSIX definition (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206), every line you write should end with "\n".

You might considering to initialise spf_rec with "\n" rather than "".

Also, as "Anand S Kumar" said, without an append, the file is overwritten at every "while x

I think that if you open the Ouput_SPF_Records.txt file with "vi", you will see the last line written (unless an exception occurred on the last execution of the cycle, causing the file to be just "").

In other words, the problem is that many software may not read a line that doesn't respect the POSIX standard, and because your file is probably composed by a unique line that doesn't respect this standard, the file won't be read at all.